# Formatting a macro to work with single line if statements

Tags: c++, boost

I am using the boost logging framework, which might be irrelevant for this question, but I want to have a macro in the form of `LOG(sev)` where `sev` is one of the log levels and I can standardize the format of the output.

```
#define LOG_LOCATION \
  boost::log::attribute_cast<boost::log::attributes::mutable_constant<int>>(boost::log::core::get()->get_global_attributes()["Line"]).set(__LINE__); \
  boost::log::attribute_cast<boost::log::attributes::mutable_constant<std::string>>(boost::log::core::get()->get_global_attributes()["File"]).set(__FILE__); \
  boost::log::attribute_cast<boost::log::attributes::mutable_constant<std::string>>(boost::log::core::get()->get_global_attributes()["Function"]).set(__func__);

#define LOG(sev) LOG_LOCATION BOOST_LOG_SEV(slg, sev)

extern boost::log::sources::severity_logger<boost::log::trivial::severity_level > slg;
```

This code snippet works in most cases where the log is on a single line, however, if I use an if in the format.

```
if(false) LOG(debug) << "Don't print this";
```

It always prints the message.  The reason is obvious, the if applies to the first statement in the macro and the rest executed, so the statement will show up (without the line number).

I am unsure of how to format this macro to work correctly.

Comment: Right, that was one of my approaches.   However if you have do {...} while(0) << "Don't print this" that is nonsense.

Comment: I am not able to follow what the code does but I think you might be able to use a function instead of objects -- `LogLocationTpee& getLogLocation(...);` and then use `#define LOG(sev) getLogLocation(slg, sev)`

Comment: Another option is [expression statements](https://godbolt.org/g/D3eLSv), supported by gcc and clang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the semicolons at the end of the three function calls in your `LOG_LOCATION` macro with commas.  This turns three statements into one partial one, that continues after the end of the expanded macro.

```
#define LOG_LOCATION \
  boost::log::attribute_cast<boost::log::attributes::mutable_constant<int>>(boost::log::core::get()->get_global_attributes()["Line"]).set(__LINE__), \
  boost::log::attribute_cast<boost::log::attributes::mutable_constant<std::string>>(boost::log::core::get()->get_global_attributes()["File"]).set(__FILE__), \
  boost::log::attribute_cast<boost::log::attributes::mutable_constant<std::string>>(boost::log::core::get()->get_global_attributes()["Function"]).set(__func__),
```

When used as you have it above, the `if` line will become

```
if(false) a, b, c, BOOST_LOG_SEV(slg, sev) << "Don't print this";
```

(Replacing those three calls to `set` with letters for brevity.)

This would work if `BOOST_LOG_SEV` expands to a single expression.  However, `BOOST_LOG_SEV` expands to a `for` statement:

```
for (::boost::log::record rec_var = (logger).open_record((BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(params_seq))); !!rec_var;)
    ::boost::log::aux::make_record_pump((logger), rec_var).stream()
```

So a different approach is necessary.

You can define 'LOG' as a class (instead of a macro) to encapsulate all the stuff in those macros.

```
class LOG {
public:
    LOG(int sev): sev(sev) { LOG_LOCATION; }
    LOG &operator<<(const char *msg) {
        BOOST_LOG_SEV(slg, sev) << msg;
        return *this;
    }
}
```

Depending on what your needs are, you can add other overloads of `operator<<` to handle `std::string`, `int`, or just make it a template class.

This may not be quite as efficient as the original when sending multiple items (`LOG(debug) << "Number " << x << " found."`) but will work as a single statement.

Comment: That was my thought too, will send compile errors with that approach tommarow. (On phone now)

Comment: Ultimately, the final part of the macro looks like this, I don't think this is a single expression `for (::boost::log::record rec_var = (logger).open_record((BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(params_seq))); !!rec_var;)\
        ::boost::log::aux::make_record_pump((logger), rec_var).stream()`

Comment: @rileymat I've added a different approach that might work

Comment: Thanks for the help, Ultimately it will not work because it depends on setting the __LINE__ __FILE__ __func__ macros being called in the right source location.  I am going to have to dig into the boost internals to create my own macro or use some other approach.  I might be able to use the macros outside of the log class  as a macro, then include the log class in a macro.

Comment: @rileymat You could change the `LOG` macro to pass the `__LINE__`, `__FILE__`, and `__func__` to `LOGhelper` (renaming my `LOG` class), then pass those 3 values to the `LOG_LOCATION` macro as parameters.